# Messing with start page in Visual Studios now opens to 403.14 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

What did I do http://localhost:11111/ doesn't work but http://localhost:11111/Home does? I've already tried Tools> Options > Open to start page and default start page

Comment: Well a 403 is fobidden so this is likely permissions of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's something wrong with routing. Check RouteConfig - there must be default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

pay attention on controller in defaults.

Comment: A 403 is forbidden. If this was true I'd expect a 404.

Comment: Thanks some how the defaults got changed